# Como referência chave estrangeira alternando tabelas

Tags: postgresql, modelo-relacional, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Eu tenho um Banco de Dados de Cidade, Estado e País. Porém quero adicionar Cidades à minha tabela e nem sempre ela contém um Estado para ser referenciado.

Entretanto, toda cidade esta localizada em um país.

Minha dúvida é: eu consigo criar uma relação em que a cidade que não tenha estado, mas que possa estar relacionada a algum país?

```
CREATE TABLE cidade
(
  id_cidade integer NOT NULL,
  id_estado integer NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(120) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cidade_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_cidade),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cidade_estado FOREIGN KEY (id_estado)
      REFERENCES estado (id_estado) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados está usando? É mySql?

Comment: Usei Postgresql

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei a tag postgresql e também removi o voto de fechamento. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo modelo apresentado, você sempre terá que fornecer um estado, já que ID_ESTADO é NOT NULL.

Eu, no seu caso, criaria um Estado chamado SEM_ESTADO ou NA (NAO APLICAVEL) para cada País, assim, seria possível tratar tudo da mesma maneira e ficaria fácil saber, por exemplo, todas as cidades que não tem um estado.

Em outras palavras, não mude o seu modelo, pois ele faz sentido. Apenas crie um Estado fictício para atender as cidades que não possuem Estado.

Answer (score 0):

Se é impossível determinar o país de todas as cidades pelo seu estado, você deve esquecer a relação estado/país quando for buscar informações de uma cidade, em vez disso, deve criar uma relação cidade/país...

id_pais integer NOT NULL